# Slowly charging laptop after charger replacement

Tags: laptop, cable, charging, charger

I have browsed questions with similar title on this site, but my case is different. Recently, my charger was not getting connected to my laptop. Then I replaced the charging cord which now connects easily with laptop (the charging light turns on when connected) but the rate of charging is too slow. It takes almost an hour to get 1 or 2 percent of charge. It is an iball Compbook Excelance laptop, two years old.

Comment: can you pull out the battery ? Is it removable ?

Comment: No, I don't think it is removable. It cannot be removed separately, I have to pull out the back cover completely then see.

Comment: are you sure that the old charger is not working ?

Comment: Yes, I mean the cord is not connecting. The adapter is fine.

Comment: what do you mean by "cord is not connecting"

Comment: The light that shows charging is not glowing on.

Comment: "Recently, my charger was not getting connected to my laptop." and  "Yes, I mean the cord is not connecting. The adapter is fine" reflect that something is physically wrong with the charger because it is "connecting" but not "working" ...choose correct wording in your questions

Comment: Your laptop might need a new battery.

Comment: My original charger was not connecting to my laptop. I have a mobile-like charger, have cord and adapter separate, cord connects to adapter via USB. Then, I used another cord with the same adapter and the charging light started glowing but the charging rate is too slow.

Comment: https://www.amazon.in/iball-LPA-3865L-Laptop-Adaptor-11-5x5-0/dp/B01N4IRAVW 
is this your charger ?

Comment: No, https://www.amazon.in/iBall-USB-Power-Adapter-Black/dp/B07JB6YHH7/ref=pd_sbs_353_3/261-3062691-4053047?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07JB6YHH7&pd_rd_r=f34838c1-f0bc-4d2e-91da-78280c5c5a6c&pd_rd_w=i4Yva&pd_rd_wg=KXfQ8&pf_rd_p=87667aae-831c-4952-ab47-0ae2a4d747da&pf_rd_r=HPQN8BH7ABWRX881W18C&psc=1&refRID=HPQN8BH7ABWRX881W18C is my charger.

Comment: There are a number of things it could be.  Are you sure the laptop is designed to charge from a 5V USB connection (that's unusual for laptops)?  If you're using a standard USB cable, it may not have wires sized for 2A.  At 2 yrs old, the battery may have exhausted its recharge cycles and it could need to be replaced.  There are other, less likely possibilities, including: a problem with the charging circuit, a problem with the power adapter, etc.  Unfortunately, this isn't something people here can know the answer to.

Comment: @fixer1234, Yes, its original charger is 5V USB connection.

Comment: Try another charging cable of good quality, if possible buy it from the manufacturer. If this doesn't help, the battery may need replacement.